# must i use the return value of a method?

Tags: java, methods, return, using

all the questions i see are about using the return value, while i want to ask about not using it.
i have a method that gets a book title, and remove all books with the same title from an array of books (library).

i wrote another method that gets a book title and remove the first book with the same title given, from the array (not 100% finished because the question is about it):

```
public Book remove(String name)
{    
    Book bookRemoved= null;
    for (int i=0; i<_noOfBooks; i++)
    {
        if (name.equals(_lib[i].getTitle()))
        {
            bookRemoved= new Book (_lib[i]);
            _lib[i]=null;
            closeGap();
        }            
    }             
    return bookRemoved;
}
```

i have another private method whose purpose is to close the gaps created in the array, and return the amount of books removed:

```
//counts the amount of books removed and closes the gaps casued by removing them
private int closeGap()
{
    int count=0;
    //number of nulls
    for (int i=0; i<_noOfBooks;i++)  //run throughout array to find # of 
nulls
    {
        if (_lib[i]==null);
        count++;  
    }

    //closing gaps        
    for(int i=0; i<_noOfBooks-1;i++)
    {
        int nextCell=i+1;
        while (_lib[nextCell]== null)  //find the next cell after _lib[i] 
that isn't null
            nextCell++;
        if (_lib[i]== null)  
        {
            _lib[i]= _lib[nextCell];   //fill nulled cell with nextCell- 
temporarily alliasing
            _lib[nextCell]=null;       //remove nectCell value -remove 
alliasing
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

when i want to use the closeGap method, i get the value 1 returned, but i cant find a way to use it to break out of the for loop without forcing it badly.
do i must use the returned value? is there a way to break out of the loop using it?

Comment: If you want to terminate a for loop prematurely, you can use [break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: The caller can safely ignore the return value. I think the last language I used that did not allow that was `Modula-2`

Comment: It's not really clear if you're asking how to use (or not use) the returned value of a method or if you're asking how to break out of a loop.  They're unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to exit a for loop. E.g.

```
public Book remove(String name)
{    
    Book bookRemoved= null;
    for (int i=0; i<_noOfBooks; i++)
    {
        if (name.equals(_lib[i].getTitle()))
        {
            bookRemoved= new Book (_lib[i]);
            _lib[i]=null;
            if (closeGap() == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }            
    }             
    return bookRemoved;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would do something as follows. Its a little vague on what set of values you want to remove. if you want to leave the loop if that returns 0 just replace

```
closeGap();
```

with

```
if(closeGap()==0)
    break;
```